# PHP and AMQP RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, amqp, php

I have a working PHP script that publishes messages to RabbitMQ that it parses out of a tab-delimited text file.  I literally copy/pasted the working code from that file to another file and wanted to establish a consumer that will retrieve messages published to the exchange, json_decode them and insert them into a database.

Every attempt and even copy/paste the sample code from PHP.net site, and even examples in SO, fail with blank white screen and no error messages, then it even kills php-fpm process.

**Any idea why the queue will not bind and what is going wrong here?**

- Nginx -> php-fpm
- PHP 5.3.x
- Macbook Pro (OSX Lion)
- RabbitMQ (librabbitmq and pecl amqp installed)

Here is one example of what I tried, but I've tried PHP.net and SO examples on AMQP docs and none work.  I can publish fine, but when I try to bind a queue it fails and eventually php-fpm locks up.

```
<?php
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*****************************************
 * MQ settings
 ****************************************/
$mq = array(
           'host' => 'localhost',
           'port' => 5672,
           'login' => 'guest',
           'password' => 'guest',
           'exchange' => 'gbus.user',
           'routing_key' => 'gbus.test.mike',
           );

/*****************************************
 * Connect to queue
 ****************************************/

$conn_args = array('host' => $mq['host'], 'port' => $mq['port'], 'login' => $mq['login'], 'password' => $mq['password']);
$conn = new AMQPConnection($conn_args);
$conn->connect();

$ch = new AMQPChannel($conn);

// Create a new queue
$q = new AMQPQueue($ch);
$q->declare('test-queue');
$q->bind($mq['exchange'],$mq['routing_key']);

?>
<br>
<font color="blue" face="arial" size="4">File Contents</font>
<hr>
<?php 
while(true){
    $msg=$q->get();
    if ($msg['count']>-1){
        echo "\n--------\n";
        print_r($msg['msg']);
        echo "\n--------\n";
    }
    sleep(1);   
}
if (!$conn->disconnect()) {
    throw new Exception('Could not disconnect');
}
?>
```

---

Here is example of what I used to publish to queue and every time I run this, I view in the RabbitMQ control panel the 20 new messages.  I limit to 20 for testing but file has tens of thousands of rows.

**Working publish code:**

```
<?php
/*****************************************
 * MQ settings
 ****************************************/
$mq = array(
           'host' => 'localhost',
           'port' => 5672,
           'login' => 'guest',
           'password' => 'guest',
           'exchange' => 'gbus.user',
           'routing_key' => 'gbus.test.mike',
           );

/*****************************************
 * Connect to queue
 ****************************************/

$conn_args = array('host' => $mq['host'], 'port' => $mq['port'], 'login' => $mq['login'], 'password' => $mq['password']);
$conn = new AMQPConnection($conn_args);
$conn->connect();

$ch = new AMQPChannel($conn);

$ex = new AMQPExchange($ch);
$ex->setName($mq['exchange']);


/*****************************************
 * Parse the file
 ****************************************/
$filename = "/tmp/Users.txt";
$board = "test";

$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));

fclose ($fd);
$delimiter = "\r\n";
$rows = explode($delimiter, $contents);
$counter = 0;
?>
<br>
<font color="blue" face="arial" size="4">File Rows (first 20)</font>
<hr>
<?php 
foreach ( $rows as $row )
{
    $counter++;
    echo "<b>Row $counter: </b> $row<br>";

    // build list columns
    list($login_name, $pwd, $account_type, $access_level, $status, $first_name, $last_name, $agent_code) = explode("\t", $row);

    // build assoc array for json
    $user = array("domain"=>$board, "username"=>$login_name, "user_id"=>$agent_code, "password"=>$pwd, "first_name"=>$first_name, "last_name"=>$last_name);

    // Publish a message to the exchange with a routing key
    $ex->publish(json_encode($user), $mq['routing_key'], AMQP_NOPARAM, array("content_type"=>"application/data"));

    if($counter == 20) {
        break;
    }
}

$ch->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I have tried all examples here and publish works, but consume fails: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/amqp.examples.php

Comment: I have also un-bound the original queue to the exchange to be sure it wasn't "stealing" the messages (not sure if it ack'ed or not as via control panel).

Comment: In bin folder of rabbmitmq folder you have **rabbitmqctl** do `rabbitmqctl list_queues` 
to list your queues **list_exchanges** will list exchanges and **list_bindings** will give you the debug information that will help you. Checkout http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html for more details. Post the dumps here that would be helpful in finding your the problem.

Comment: With removing the queue bind call, I can get it to declare, but then server crashes again.  Any time I include bind, it fails.  Not sure if just Mac OSX Lion issue; haven't tried on linux box yet.  Odd one.

Comment: Documents of AMQP on php.net are outdated ( basically not updated) , like $queue->declare is depreciated but still it is present in documents there. So be careful while learning from there. If you are using rabbitMQ then you can use "videlalvaro/php-amqplib"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the examples found here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/php?

The two you want to look at are:
emit_log.php
receive_logs.php

The library used is different to the PECL/built in library, I believe the built in one does not support consume.

Comment: work queues which is what I'm trying to accomplish fail with both Php, Pear, etc. examples.  The link you provide doesn't provide PHP examples and leads to Python examples for the queue on Rabbit's site.

Comment: The link I posted definitely shows PHP examples for me, I've used them recently and they worked 100% as expected. Btw I'm also running on a Mac OSX Lion box using homebrew.

Comment: follow the link, then mouseover the "Code" section below and they are all python links.  but i see what you mean.  will check those out and report.  i want to use AMQP lib documented at PHP.net so have to see what they require.

Comment: What that is saying is these examples are PHP versions of the official  tutorials on the RabbitMQ website - check the code of the git hub files, they are all PHP!